# Header file-name as argument

Tags: c, visual-studio, header-files, projects-and-solutions

**Objective:**
I have a list of header files (about 50 of them), 
And each header-file has few arrays with constant elements.
I need to write a program to count the elements of the array. And create some other form of output (which will be used by the hardware group).

**My solution:**
I included all the 50 odd files and wrote an application. And then I dumped all the elements of the array into the specified format.

**My environment:**
Visual Studio V6, Windows XP

**My problem:**
Each time there is a new set of Header files, I am now changing the VC++ project settings to point to the new set of header files, and then rebuild.

**My question:**

A bit in-sane though,

- Is there any way to mention the
  header from some command line
  arguments or something?
- I just want to avoid re-compiling the
  source every time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard C and C++ allow you to use a macro in:

```
#include SOME_MACRO_HERE
```

The expanded value of `SOME_MACRO_HERE` must look correct for a `#include` directive.

Hence, in principle, you could use the MSVC equivalent of:

```
cc -DSOME_MACRO_HERE='<actualheader.h>' sourcefile.c
```

Or:

```
cc -DSOME_MACRO_HERE='"actualheader.h"' sourcefile.c
```

This seems to provide you with an answer to your first bullet-question.

I'm not convinced you can avoid recompilation - you can (perhaps) avoid editing, though.

Comment: +1 Actually I use something like the above method. I actually do not edit the source code even now, I only change the project setting.

Answer (score 1):

Headers are included at compile time so there is no means to change/add headers at runtime.

Why don't you just write a short and simple Perl script that will parse headers and count number of array items?

Comment: Eventually I am thinking of some perl or ruby script. But just wanted to know, if there is some other method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I arrived at a solution that works.

- Step-1: The header file-names would
  be predefined
- Step-2: Headers (set) with different
  parameter values will be placed in
  different folders
- Step-3: While compiling, point to the
  path with the appropriate headers

The solution is not what I wanted, but still, it was best I could figure out.